# Finding all reflexive binary relations of a set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

Let A = $\{1,2,3\}$. What is the total number of reflexive binary relations on $P(A)$?

What I've tried to do is: Let $R$ a relation on $P(A)$. For it to be reflexive, the following must be true: $$\forall a \in A , (a,a) \in R$$

There are ${{2^{2}}^3}^2$ total possible relations on $P(A)$. I just can't seem to understand what do I need to subtract from that value to get the answer.

Comment: Hint: the diagonal always has to be filled in, so you don't get to count them as boolean "bits".

Comment: I don't quite understand what you meant by "diagonal" and "boolean bits". Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Yep sure. See the image in my answer below. This is a blank grid onto which we can represent any $7$ by $7$ relation (the choice of $7$ is arbitrary- it applies for any number $n$). A relation can be represented using a grid like this by colouring the squares red or leaving them white. Red means those two elements are related, white means they're not. The diagonal must always be red.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general answer for the number of reflexive binary relations on any finite set $X$ is as follows. Consider every relation as turning on/off squares in a grid of size $|X| \times |X|$.

In every such relation, we must have $(x, x)$ set to "on" (or "true", or $1$, or whatever you like to represent that it's in the relation).

So, we only have $|X|^2 - |X|$ choices to turn on or off.

So, the answer is:

$$2^{|X|^2 - |X|}$$

Now, in your case, $X$ is the *powerset* of $A$, i.e. $P(A)$, and the powerset size is always given by

$$|P(A)| = 2^{|A|}= 2^3 = 8$$

So you just plug it in to the above formula for your result, i.e.

$$2^{|P(A)|^2 - |P(A)|} = 2^{|P(A)|(|P(A)| - 1)} = 2^{(2^3)(2^3 - 1)} \\ = 2^{8(8-1)} = 2^{56}$$

---

Visually, you can see that the $|X|^2 - |X| = |X|(|X| - 1)$ term makes sense from the following grid. Imagine shifting the bottom-right triangle of grid cells upwards to make a rectangle of size $|X|(|X| - 1)$.

[image]

What does this grid represent? Well, this particular one is a starting point for representing any reflexive binary relation on a set with $7$ elements. But the same approach can be used to represent any binary relation on a finite set. As it stands, this is the identity relation, mapping all elements to themselves only. A red square at position $(x, y)$ denotes that $x$ is related to $y$. Starting from the identity relation, we can build any relation whatsoever by colouring $0$ or more of the remaining white squares in red. How many ways are there to do this? Well, there are $2$ choices, red and white, so combinatorics would tell us that there are $2^s$ ways to do this, where $s$ is the number of white squares remaining.

Comment: Just to make it clear, what does every square in the grid represent? What does a red square represent?

Comment: Good point. I'll elaborate in the answer.

Comment: First of all thanks for the detailed explanation. I've tried reading what you've said a bunch of times and a few things still remain unclear to me. $X$ in your example is actually $P(A)$, and for a relation to be reflexive by definition it must hold all instance of $(a,a) | a \in P(A)$. Having that in mind, I still cant figure out what the grid represents. You've said that the grid itself represents a single reflexive relation, and that each square in the grid is actually a single value of $(a.b) | a,b \in P(A)$.

Comment: From that I derive that each red square represents the value $(a,a) | a \in P(A)$, meaning that the grid as a whole, indeed as you stated, represents a reflexive relation. Now comes the part which I don't fully grasp. "As it stands, this is the identify relation, mapping all elements to themselves only. A red square at position $(x,y)$ denotes that x is related to y". What does `identify relation` mean? Did you actually mean `identity relation`. Also, what does `x related to y` means? As far as I know, $x,y \in P(A)$.

Comment: You'll have to excuse me but this is the first time anyone tries to explain binary relation to me while using a grid.

Comment: Orka YES well spotted I did mean *identity* relation not identify. I use that word a lot in work haha. A binary relation on a set $X$ is just itself a set of pairs $(x, y)$ with both $x$ and $y$ drawn from $X$. The set of *all* pairs is the grid I've shown. You are right about the red square meaning. The reason this question is trick is because your set $X$ is *already* a complicated object: the powerset of another set $A$. We then define a relation over this $X$, making it an even more complex object, whose elements are *pairs* of *sets*.

Comment: Now I finally get it. A really interesting approach to solve the problem I posed. Thanks for all the help, I'm marking this as the answer!

Comment: Orka, I am glad to hear that my explanation has clicked with you. Just as an aside, you can go further with this: if you can use a $2D$ plane (like a chessboard of any size) to represent *binary* relations. Then you can use $3D$ space to represent *ternary* relations. After that, the spatial visualisation technique doesn't really work as unfortunately in this universe our brains can only comprehend $3$ spatial dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

We have $P(A) = \big\{\{\},\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\big\}$. So $P(A) \times P(A)$ has $8 \cdot 8 = 64$ elements. In these $64$ elements, as in your definition for reflexivity, $8$ of them **must** be in our reflexive relation, namely $$\big\{\{\},\{\}\big\},\big\{\{1\},\{1\}\big\}, \big\{\{2\},\{2\}\big\},\big\{\{3\},\{3\}\big\},\big\{\{1,2\},\{1,2\}\big\},\big\{\{1,3\},\{1,3\}\big\}, \big\{\{2,3\},\{2,3\}\big\},\big\{\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\big\}$$

For other $64-8  = 56$ elements of $P(A)\times P(A)$, there are two options for each element (either in the relation set or not) so in total, we have $2^{56}$ reflexive relations on $P(A)$.